# Problema al querer mostrar una lista de datos en una una vista laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

hola mi problema esta al querer visualizar un listado de datos en una vista, 
de esta forma visualizo la data de una tabla , sin problemas

controlador

```
     public function index(Request $request)
        {
          $datos_anticipo=\IMSUR\anticipo::orderby('cod_liquidacion','DESC')
                            ->paginate(6);

           return view ('anticipos.pago_anticipo',compact('datos_anticipo'));
```

pero ahora lo que quiero hacer es listar solo algunos datos de ciertos modelos ya relacionados en este caso de los modelos Liquidaciones, Proveedores y Liquidaciones_pago_anticipo, donde el modelo Liquidaciones es un puente para acceder a los datos de Proveedores desde Liquidaciones_pago_anticipo.

y lo que quiero hacer es visualizar todos los anticipos que tenga el usuario que inicio secion, y los datos a mostrarse en la lista , son el cod_liquidacion del modelo Liquidaciones_pago_anticipo, proveedor del modelo Proveedores y un boton que visualiza el resto de los datos del anticipo
ademas de un buscador por el numero del codigo de liquidacion

lo que ise fue esto

controlador

```
  public function index(Request $request)
    {
      $cod_proveed = Auth::user()->cod_prov;  //guardamos en una variable el cod_proveedor del proveedor q se haya logeado

      $cod_liquidacion = $request->get('cod_liqui'); // se guarda en una variable el codigo de liquidacion introducido desde la vista para realizar una busqueda

  $datos_anticipo=\IMSUR\Liquidaciones_pago_anticipo::with(['liqui_a'])->where('liqui_a->cod_proveedor',$cod_proveed)
                        ->liquidacion($cod_liquidacion)  // acceso a funcion scoope para el buscador
                        ->paginate(6);

       return view ('anticipos.pago_anticipo',compact('datos_anticipo'));

    }
```

estos son mis modelos
Liquidaciones

```
   class Liquidaciones extends Model
    {
        protected $table='liquidaciones';
        protected $primaryKey = 'cod_liquidacion';
        protected $fillable = ['cod_columna',
                               'cod_liquidacion',
                               'fecha_ingreso',
                               'fecha_liquidacion',
                               'cod_proveedor'];

        public function proveedor_p(){
          return $this->belongsTo('IMSUR\Proveedores','cod_proveedor');
        }

        public function pago_a(){                       
      return $this->hasMany('IMSUR\Liquidaciones_pago_anticipo','cod_liquidacion','cod_liquidacion');
    }
```

modelo Proveedores

```
     class Proveedores extends Model
 {
        protected $table='proveedores';
        protected $primaryKey = 'cod_proveedor';
        protected $fillable=['cod_proveedor',
                             'proveedor',
                             'cod_cooperativa',
                             'cod_origen'];

        public function liqui_p(){
          return $this->hasMany('IMSUR\Liquidaciones','cod_proveedor');
        }
    }
```

modelo Liquidaciones_pago_anticipo

```
class Liquidaciones_pago_anticipo extends Model
{
    protected $table='liquidaciones_pago_anticipo';
    //protected $primaryKey = 'cod_anticipo_pago';
    protected $fillable=['cod_anticipo_pago',
                         'cod_liquidacion',
                         'fecha_pago',
                         'monto',
                         'cod_persona',
                         'cod_grupo_anticipo_pago',
                         'usuario'];

    public function liqui_a(){
      return $this->belongsTo('IMSUR\Liquidaciones','cod_liquidacion');
    }

    public function scopeLiquidacion ($query, $cod_liquidacion){
      if($cod_liquidacion)
      return $query->where('cod_liquidacion','LIKE',"%$cod_liquidacion%");
    }
```

y asi estoy llamando desde mi vista index

```
<table class="table">

  <thead>
    <th>Codigo</th>
    <th>Proveedor</th>
    <th>Vista Factura</th>
  </thead>
  @foreach($datos_anticipo as $anti)
  <tbody>
    <td>{{$anti->cod_liquidacion}}</td>

    <td>{{ $anti->liqui_a->proveedor_p->proveedor }}</td>
    <td>
        {!!link_to_route('anticipo.show',$title = 'Ver factura',$parameters = $anti->cod_liquidacion, $attributes=['class'=>'btn btn-primary'])!!}
    </td>
  </tbody>
  @endforeach
</table>
```

pero me sale el siguiente error

```
ErrorException in AnticipoController.php line 24: Trying to get property of non-object
```

podrian decirme donde esta mi error y como solucionarlo, grasias.

Answer (score 1):

lo que ocurre es que `liqui_a->cod_proveedor` no existe en el modelo `Liquidaciones_pago_anticipo` y tampoco `liquidacion`

En todo caso Habria qie usar un `subquery` y en la sentencia `use()` pasamos el parametro a usar y en cuanto a `LIKE` hay que concatenar la cadena

Y nos resultaria algo así

```
$datos_anticipo=\IMSUR\Liquidaciones_pago_anticipo::with(['liqui_a' => function($query) use ($cod_proveed){
                             $query->where('cod_proveedor',$cod_proveed);
                        }])
                        ->where('cod_liquidacion','LIKE',"%".$cod_liquidacion."%")
                        ->get();
```

Prueba con `return $datos_anticipo;` para ver que sale

Ademas asegurate de que estos 2 existan

```
$cod_proveed = Auth::user()->cod_prov;
$cod_liquidacion = $request->get('cod_liqui');
//$cod_liquidacion = $request->Input('cod_liqui');// Si lo mandas desde `form[action]`
//$cod_liquidacion = $request->cod_liqui;// si lo mandas por AJAX {cod_liqui:cod_liqui}
```

Comment: FatalErrorException in AnticipoController.php line 44: syntax error, unexpected '}'      ,      me salio ese error me fije pero no falta ninguna llave en lo que mandaste

Comment: @reivinbonshueder falta un punto y coma, si te fijas bien... `$query->where('cod_proveedor',$cod_proveed);`

Comment: coloque el punto y coma que faltaba pero me salio el siguiente errorya tambien               ErrorException in a8a95d02a91d2183cdc2141cf6890835 line 42: Trying to get property of non-object (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\web-imsur-laravel\resources\views\anticipos\pago_anticipo.blade.php)